# Subtitle settings in iTunes content on iOS are wrong

Tags: iphone, itunes, video, movie, subtitle

I am watching *Quantum of Solace* on my iPhone 5 (iOS 6.0.1), purchased from iTunes.

I noticed that the subtitles were in Spanish. I thought maybe the setting was wrong, but it was set to "Off". I then tried to switch the setting from "Off" to "US English", and now the subtitles disappeared.

So, "Subtitles: Off" gives me Spanish, "Subtitles: US English" gives me nothing.

Is it possible that the movie itself is messed up? All my other movies seem to be working fine, it's just this one, so I'm thinking it's not my phone.

**Edit:** A little further into the movie now, and the settings are back to normal. English is English, and Off is Off. But the first few minutes are still screwed up. I'm thinking it's a problem with iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the Spanish subs are hardcoded into the movie (i.e. part of the video track, not a separate track). This is often the case for English language films with small portions of foreign languages. My copy of Quantum of Solace (not from iTunes) has some hardcoded subs for Spanish parts around the 28 minute mark (haven't watched the full movie in some time, there may be others).

I'm not sure that would explain why the English subtitle selection doesn't display anything however.

Comment: If they were hardcoded, wouldn't they stay on regardless of the subtitle settings? They disappear when I pick English. I'm not talking about the hardcoded translation subtitles for the Spanish speaking. I mean the subtitles are *in Spanish.*